# Extract words from word-Dictionary Line-By Line

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two files, one has summary (contains many rows extracted from csv file) and other has list of words (in row in csv file). I read both the files, and got Array[String] for each one:

```
val summary: Array[String] = ...
val wordList: Array[String] = ...
```

For each line in `summary`, I want to extract the list of the words that also exist in `wordList`,

Sample data in `summary`:

```
hi how are you
I am good.how about you.
I would like to have tea.
```

Sample data in `wordList`:

```
good
tea
you
like
```

Expected result:

```
you
good,you
like,tea
```

Comment: Why don't you import the csv directly into a dataframe? https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: This is clearly an assignment. It would be best if you showed what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck. Also, you've tagged it with Spark but have Arrays - are those really RDDs?

Comment: It's also a duplicate of several other questions, including one I'd forgotten I'd answered...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark filtering based on matches in two Arrays in RDD's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145019/spark-filtering-based-on-matches-in-two-arrays-in-rdds)

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32145019/spark-filtering-based-on-matches-in-two-arrays-in-rdds/32147763#32147763

Answer (score 1):

As someone points out, you don't need Spark:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

val results = summary.map(l => {
  var result = ArrayBuffer[String]();
  wordList.foreach(w => {if (l.contains(w)) result.append(w)});
  result.toArray.mkString(",")
}).filter(l => l.length > 0)
```

Comment: I am getting only blank array :(  please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final answer, I figured out:

```
val broadcast_wordList=sc.broadcast(wordList)

def concat(ss: String*) = ss filter (_.nonEmpty) mkString ", "

val results_part1 = summary_arraylist. repartition(1).map{l=>

var t=broadcast_wordList.value.map(w=>if(l.contains(w)){w}else{""})

print(l)

var tt=t.filter(ll=>ll.length>0).toArray.mkString("|")

concat(l,tt)
```

Answer (score -1):

@David Griffin. when i tried your code, it was first giving error saying RDD cant contain RDD. So modified your code by broadcasting the the worlist, and then using the broadcasted variable in the code.

```
val broadcast_wordList=sc.broadcast(wordList)

val results = summary_arraylist.map {l=>
val result = ArrayBuffer[String]();
broadcast_wordList.value.foreach(w=> {if(l.contains(w))  result.append(w)});
result.toArray.mkString(",")
 }
```

Since i want all rows, even the blank rows(where there is no matching), so i removed "filter" from the code.
But still, i am getting blank arrays as my output.

Here is the output:

[image].